# What properties do i have to give my controller index method?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, database, entity-framework

I am building a project for school. I am almost there but there is one error I can't fix.
I am making a bike reservation asp.net website.
The error says I pass a list to the index page of reservations and it expects an IEnumerable.
I already tried making the expected a list, but that also gives an error.

I have seen other fixes of this problem, but I can't get it to work.

Here is my original index method.

```
    // GET: Reservations
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var reservations = db.Reservations.Include(r => r.Bike).Include(r => r.Customer).Include(r => r.DropoffStore).Include(r => r.PickupStore);
        return View(reservations.ToList());
    }
```

Here is my new Controller index method that i got from someone else, but i dont know why i wont work:

```
    // GET: Reservations
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var reservations = db.Reservations.Include(r => r.Bike).Include(r => r.Customer).Include(r => r.DropoffStore).Include(r => r.PickupStore);

        IEnumerable<ReservationViewModel> reservationViewModels = new List<ReservationViewModel>();

        foreach (var reservation in reservations)
        {
            var reservationViewModel = new ReservationViewModel
            {
               (PROPERTY)
            };

            reservationViewModels.ToList().Add(reservationViewModel);

        }

        return View(reservationViewModels);
    }
```

Here is my index page:

```
@model IEnumerable<ASP.NET_Framwork_for_real_bitch.ViewModels.ReservationViewModel>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Reservation.Customer.FirstName)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Reservation.Customer.LastName)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Reservation.Customer.Email)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Reservation.Customer.Gender)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Reservation.DropoffStore_Id)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Reservation.PickupStore_Id)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Reservation.StartDate)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Reservation.EndDate)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Reservation.Customer.FirstName)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Reservation.Customer.LastName)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Reservation.Customer.Email)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Reservation.Customer.Gender)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Reservation.DropoffStore.StoreName)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Reservation.PickupStore.StoreName)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Reservation.StartDate)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Reservation.EndDate)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.Reservation.Id }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.Reservation.Id })
    </td>
</tr>
}

</table>
```

This is the exact error:

```
The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[ASP.NET_Framwork_for_real_bitch.Models.Reservation]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[ASP.NET_Framwork_for_real_bitch.ViewModels.ReservationViewModel]'.
```

my Whole ReservationViewModel:

```
using ASP.NET_Framwork_for_real_bitch.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace ASP.NET_Framwork_for_real_bitch.ViewModels
{
    public class ReservationViewModel
    {
        private BikeShoppaModel db = new BikeShoppaModel();
        public Reservation Reservation { get; set; }
        public SelectList DropoffStore_Id { get; private set; }
        public SelectList PickupStore_Id { get; private set; }
        public SelectList Bikes { get; private set; }
        public SelectList CustomerGender { get; set; }
        public int TotalDays { get; set; }
        public double TotalPrice { get; set; }
        public ReservationViewModel()
        {
            DropoffStore_Id = new SelectList(db.Stores, "Id", "StoreName");
            PickupStore_Id = new SelectList(db.Stores, "Id", "StoreName");
            Bikes = new SelectList(db.Bikes, "Id", "Brand");
            CustomerGender = new SelectList(db.Customers, "Id", "Gender");
        }
        public ReservationViewModel(int id) : this()
        {
            Reservation = db.Reservations.Find(id);
            TotalDays = (Reservation.EndDate.Date - Reservation.StartDate.Date).Days + 1;
        }

        public void Save()
        {
            if(Reservation.Id > 0)
            {
                db.Entry(Reservation).State = EntityState.Modified;
            }
            else
            {
                db.Reservations.Add(Reservation);
            }



            db.SaveChanges();
        }   
    }
}
```

my Reservations model:

```
public class Reservation
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("Customer")]
        [Display(Name = "Customer")]
        public int Customer_Id { get; set; }
        public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("Bike")]
        public int Bike_Id { get; set; }
        public Bike Bike { get; set; }


        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [Column(TypeName = "Date")]
        [Display(Name = "Start date")]
        public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [Column(TypeName = "Date")]
        [Display(Name = "End date")]
        public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("PickupStore")]
        [Display(Name = "Pickup store")]
        public int PickupStore_Id { get; set; }
        public Store PickupStore { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("DropoffStore")]
        [Display(Name = "Dropoff store")]
        public int DropoffStore_Id { get; set; }
        public Store DropoffStore { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: You are returning a `List` of the wrong thing.  Your second example (the one you got from someone) shows them returning an `IEnumerable` of **ReservationViewModel** not an `IEnumerable` of **Reservation**.  I think you were on the right track but focusing on the wrong part of the error message.  Look closer at fully qualified model types of each part of your error message.

Comment: System.Collections.Generic.List1[ASP.NET_Framwork_for_real_bitch. **Models.Reservation** ]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable1[ASP.NET_Framwork_for_real_bitch. **ViewModels.ReservationViewModel** ]

Comment: So i have to return a `IEnumerable` of type Reservation?

Comment: No, you need to return one of type ReservationViewModel.  The top line of the .cshtml file (the view) tells you what type its expecting.  If you don't send in a list of that type, then it won't work.  Also, a side note.  A `List<someObject>` can be sent anywhere you see `IEnumerable<someObject>`.  The reason for this is that an `IEnumerable` is just anything that can be enumerated...a List, array, Collection, etc.  So, sending a List<ReservationViewModel>() will work in this case.

Comment: In the second Index, I send an IEnumerable of type `ReservationViewModel` right? But I send an empty one. I don't know what properties i have to pass and how to right that. The other guy gave me this as tip: `OneProperty = reservation.AnotherProperty`

Comment: Your friend is being very helpful for you.  If I have a list of one type (Reservation)....but need to send a list of another type(ReservationViewModel).....perhaps if I looped through the list I have and `for each` one of those, created an object of the type I need....then I could send that list of those newly created things to the view.

Comment: I got it, thanks for the help/suggestion!

Comment: Your new index controller action still won't work?

Comment: i think in the second Index, you don't need to call ``.ToList()`` inside loop, change just the declaration of ``reservationViewModels`` to ``List<ReservationViewModel> reservationViewModels = new List<ReservationViewModel>();``

Comment: Anytime - good luck and happy coding!